# How to open modal window when clicking a WP menu link?

Tags: menus

I'm making my first site with WP, I'm a Joomla Developper.
I'm using wisten theme, and WP 3.9.2

I want to create a link in my the navigation that opens a modal window (not a new page) on click.
Example -  http://kendo.mx , when you click the LOGIN link
I have no clue of how I should do this in WordPress.

The Jquery code for such an operation is not very difficult, the code is here :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/hBX6E/2/
```

but I have no clue of how to integrate it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bootstrap's modal you could use this hook in your function.php file top do that:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_atts', 10, 3 );
function menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The ID of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 24;

  // inspect $item
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'modal';
    $atts['data-target'] = '#IDofModal';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use something like the title to match on the menu item as the ID can differ between environments if they are not an exact duplicate.